# Copy values from a Pivot Table to another

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I would like to copy values from a pivot table (without titles and total amount) to another sheet.

I want to copy what is framed (sheets(“CLE”)).

Here the TCD :

[image: tcd]

And paste it in column H (sheets(“IML”).

I tried this following code but I have a "Can't read the PivotTables property" error.

```
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TCD CLE")
    pt.PivotFields("Montant").DataRange.Select
    
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("IML").Select
        Range("G2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Do you have any ideas why I have this message ?
Thank you !

Comment: [This article should be helpful](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/).

Comment: Thank you @BigBen. This article is very useful ! So I tried with this code : `Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
pt.PivotFields("Montant").DataRange.Select
Selection.Copy 
` 
But I have an error ‘can’t read the DataRange property’

Comment: Hmm. Given your current setup, you could use `pt.DataBodyRange`.